# Determine the GPU memory vendor name under linux

Tags: nvidia, gpu

Is it possible to determine the vendor name of the memory used in a dedicated GPU in linux?

Under Windows, there is a tool called GPU-Z that shows this value, tho under linux it seems there is no tool to display that value...

GPU I'm using is a Geforce GTX 1060 using Cuda8 and Nvidia proprietary drivers

Cheers

Comment: I no longer have a NVidia card and I can't find an old file, but if you have `lshw` do `sudo lshw -html > /path/to/some/htmlfile.html` and view it in a browser.  Very nice full hardware listing.

Comment: Thanks, I read in a nother comment that apparently the Nvidia linux driver does not support that feature so it might not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this NVIDIA forum thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1018512/linux/memory-brand-type/), there's no way to get the vendor name in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this piece of information just today regarding an AMD Radeon RX 580 to update its BIOS and had no access to a Windows PC. I tried each and every command I could find on different forums but nothing worked.

So I gave up until I opened my mining rig under HiveOS and saw in the GPU list the amount of VRAM in MB, and the manufacturer (eg : Hynix or Samsung GDDR6 for my Nvidia Cards, or SK Hynix or Micron for my AMD cards).

So to get the GPU memory manufacturer, simply download and install on a USB device [HiveOS distro](https://hiveon.com/knowledge-base/getting_started/quick_install/), then boot it up, click on your mining farm name, select a worker, and scroll down to the list of GPUs. The GPU memory manufacturer is included.

Obviously this is a workaround and there should be a command to get this piece of information on a vanilla Linux. HiveOS source code does not seem to be available anymore.

Comment: Ye I also noticed that nowadays hiveos shows the vendor... still wondering how they do it.